# Extracting formulae from TeX/ Metafont

Tags: fonts, metafont

I wish to create a program outside of Metafont that creates letters mathematically. In researching any available resources, I have found Metafont as a language to create 'mathematically described' characters and shapes and wish to use implement the formulae that it uses to describe its shapes, in my program. Is it possible to extract the formulae that creates an intial shape from Metafont?

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean, the metafont program for the character is a program (formulae) for the character. If you have the metafont source then you have that, you cannot extract that from the resulting font, just as you can not get a tex source from a pdf resulting from a tex document.  But you may prefer to use opentype fonts and extract (subject to licence constraints) the curves from the fonts, which are that case in the font.

Comment: I guess you are asking about the algorithm itself, so the program that you want to write takes a mathematical description of the shape of a character as input and produces the rendered character shape on the screen, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Marijn. That is correct.